# On the uniqueness in the proof of the universal property of product

Tags: category-theory

A standard result of category theory is the universal property for product:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. For any set $A$ and functions
> $$
>   \left\{
>   \begin{aligned} 
>    f &\colon A \rightarrow X \,, \\
>    g &\colon A \rightarrow Y \,,
>  \end{aligned}
>  \right.
> $$
> there exists a **unique** function $m \colon A \rightarrow X \times Y$ such that, given projections
> $$
>   \left\{
>   \begin{aligned}
>     \pi_{1} &\colon X \times Y \rightarrow X \,, \\
>     \pi_{2} &\colon X \times Y \rightarrow Y \,,
>   \end{aligned}
>   \right.
> $$
> the following compositions hold for $m \colon A \rightarrow X \times Y$:
> $$
>   \left\{
>   \begin{aligned}
>     \pi_{1}\circ m = f \,, \\
>     \pi_{2}\circ m = g \,.
>   \end{aligned}
>   \right.
> $$

A proof needs to address both existence and the uniqueness of $m$. Here is my proof:

---

Given an arbitrary $a \in A$, we have
$$
  \left\{
  \begin{aligned}
    f(a) &= x \in X \,, \\
    g(a) &= y \in Y \,,
  \end{aligned}
  \right.
$$
which may be written as $(x,y) = (f(a), g(a))$. We define function $m: A\rightarrow X\times Y$ as $m(a):=(f(a),g(a))$ yielding
$$
  \left\{
  \begin{aligned}
    (\pi_{1} \circ m)(a) &= \pi_{1}(f(a), g(a)) = f(a) \,, \\
    (\pi_{2} \circ m)(a) &= \pi_{2}(f(a), g(a)) = g(a) \,.
  \end{aligned}
  \right.
$$

Since $a$ is selected arbitrarily, we have
$$
  \left\{
  \begin{aligned}
    \pi_{1} \circ m &= f \,, \\
    \pi_{2} \circ m &= g \,.
  \end{aligned}
  \right.
$$

---

But, I don’t know how to incorporate the uniqueness of $m$ into it. Can one explain how I am supposed to do so?

Comment: Could you double check that you have proved the existence? Have you ever defined $m$?

Comment: For uniqueness, assume some other function $m'$ satisfies those properties and show $m =m'$. You can do this by showing that $m(a)=m'(a)$ for all $a\in A$

Comment: @Apass.Jack: You are right. I added the definition of $m$ to the theorem statement.

Comment: @User I think what Apass.Jack meant was that there's no definition of $m$ *in your proof*. $m$ just suddenly appears without being defined in the equation after "which may be written as...". I strongly suspect that $m$ is supposed to be defined by that line, but you should make it explicit.

Comment: @S.C.: $m$ is defined in the theorem statement. So, why do I need to redefine it in the proof, instead of just citing it in the flow of deduction? Please note that it is just like the case of the projection functions $\pi_{1}$ and $\pi_{2}$. They are only defined in the theorem statement and are only used in the proof.

Comment: @User The theorem is (1) there exists an $m$ satisfying the given equations and (2) that $m$ is the only function satisfying those equations. It doesn't actually contain a definition of $m$. Your proof should have one along the lines of $m(a) = $... The theorem statement doesn't define the projections either, but you should know how they're defined (and indeed you implicitly use their definitions in your proof).

Comment: @S.C.: Now I see. What I had supplied was just the signature of $m$ not its definition. So, I edited the proof accordingly. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof of existence is good now. To finish it off, you should start with some (possibly different) function $A \to X \times Y$ (I'll call it $n$) such that $\pi_1 \circ n = f$ and $\pi_2 \circ n = g$. Your goal is then to prove that $n = m$. I suggest proving that for all $a$, $n(a) = m(a)$.

Just as a tip, the first paragraph of your proof (the one that motivates the definition of $m$) is pretty much the proof of uniqueness. You'll use very similar reasoning.

Comment: Thanks for your help!